# Apache2 - rewrite a bunch of specified pathname URLs to one URL

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, seo

I need to rewrite a bunch of urls (about 100 or so) for SEO purposes, and there may be more being added in the future (probably another 50-100 later on).  I need a flexible way of doing this and so far, the only way I can think of is to edit the .htaccess file using the rewrite engine.

For example, I have a bunch of urls like this (please note that the query string is irrelevant, and dynamic; it could be anything.  I was only using them purely as an example.  I am only focusing on the pathname--the part between the hostname and query string, as marked in bold below):

http://example.com/**seo_term1**?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=seo_term
http://example.com/**another_seo_term2**?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=seo_term

http://example.com/**yet_another_seo_term3**?utm_source=example_ad_network&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=seo_term
http://example.com/**foobar_seo_term4**

http://example.com/**blah_seo_term5**?test=1

etc...

And they are all being rewritten to (for now): `http://example.com/`

What's the most efficient/effective way of doing this so that I may be able to add more terms in the future?

One solution I came across is to do this (in the .htaccess file):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [NC,QSA]
```

However, the problem with this solution is that even invalid urls (such as `http://example.com/blah`) will be rewritten to `http://example.com` instead of giving a 404 code (which is what it is supposed to do anyway).  I'm still trying to figure out how all this works, and the only way I can think of is to write 100 more `RewriteCond` statements (such as: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/seo_term1 [NC,OR]`) before the `RewriteRule` directive.  For example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/seo_term1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/another_seo_term2 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/yet_another_seo_term3 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/foobar_seo_term4 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/blah_seo_term5 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [NC,QSA]
```

But that doesn't sound very efficient to me.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3):

The first improvement you can make is that you don't need the `RewriteCond` lines at all.

```
RewriteRule /seo_term1 / [NC,QSA]
```

Does exactly what your two lines are doing now.

The second improvement you could make is using a [`RewriteMap`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/rewritemap.html).  The rewrite map itself is can be updated without restarting Apache.

```
RewriteMap seo txt:/etc/apache2/maps/seo.txt
RewriteRule (.*) ${seo:$1} [NC,QSA]
```

and `seo.txt` contains

```
/seo_term1 /
/seo_term2 /
```

Note: I haven't actually used a RewriteMap for several years.  The above config may need some tweaking due to my imperfect memory.

Comment: Thanks, this is sort of what I was looking for...  unfortunately it didn't work. I keep getting 400 errors for anything in the map text file.  I tried to look up some more examples for RewriteMap but there's nothing that seems to explain this in further detail.  Thanks for trying at least.

Answer (score 1):

A regex should be pretty capable of pulling this off.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/[^\?]+\?(?=.*(utm_source\=(google|msn|yahoo)))(?=.*(utm_medium\=(cpc|ppc)))(?=.*(utm_campaign\=[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+))
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

The above would match only a string that contains all the parameters specified, regardless of the leading (pre-?) string.

**Edit ...**

Okay, you've changed your question quite a bit now. But thankfully, its even more straightforward.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(seo_term1|seo_term2)(.*)?
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=301]
```

Just change/edit/add values as necessary.

Comment: utm_source won't always be "google" and utm_medium won't always be "cpc", those were just examples.  Also, what if someone puts an invalid value anyway (due to malicious reasons or what not), e.g. `http://www.example.com/blahblah?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium...` I would want this to 404.

Comment: Well list what all the possible `utm_source`s are and what all the `utm_medium`s are then!

Comment: I think I will re-word my question then; I really only care about the pathname, not the query string.  The query string is totally dynamic and could even end with something like ?test=1 for example.